# Can you coat a weapon with adamantine?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons, special-materials

My dwarven cleric needs a buff lvl10 and I have 1000 gp. I know I can get an adamantine weapon with this but since my character is greedy I was wondering if I could just get a master Smith to coat the blade I already have to save money.

Answer (score 5):

## Rules for buying, but not for coating directly - but ask your DM

Xanathar's Guide to Everything provides an [optional rule](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/118811/are-the-rules-in-xanathars-guide-to-everything-clarifications-in-addition-to-th) regarding Adamantine Weapons found in [Chapter 2](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/xgte/dungeon-masters-tools#AdamantineWeapons).

> Melee weapons and ammunition made of or coated with adamantine are unusually effective when used to break objects. Whenever an adamantine weapon or piece of ammunition hits an object, the hit is a critical hit.
>
> The adamantine version of a melee weapon or of ten pieces of ammunition costs 500 gp more than the normal version, whether the weapon or ammunition is made of the metal or coated with it.

Just paying the 500gp to coat it seems like a reasonable option - but you'd need to ask your DM on this application of the optional rule above.

### No differing effects except on Objects

Per the text above, an Adamantine weapon is not differentiated from mundane weapons except for how to treat hits on objects.

Compare this to Silver coating which can bypass some resistances against mundane weapons (and costs much less!)

Comment: Just like werewolves and certain devils resist non-magical weapons that aren't silvered, Xorns, Gargoyles, and some other monsters resist damage from nonmagical weapons that aren't adamantine. So the reason to buy or upgrade a weapon with adamantine is the same as silver, basically, just against different beasties.

Answer (score 3):

## 5th Edition does not distinguish between "Adamantine Weapons" and "Adamantine *Coated* Weapons"

The *Xanathar's Guide to Everything* entry on [Adamantine Weapons](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/xgte/dungeon-masters-tools#AdamantineWeapons) (p. 78) describes them like this:

> Melee weapons and ammunition **made of or coated with adamantine** are unusually effective when used to break objects. Whenever an adamantine weapon or piece of ammunition hits an object, the hit is a critical hit.
>
> The adamantine version of a melee weapon or of ten pieces of ammunition costs 500 gp more than the normal version, **whether the weapon or ammunition is made of the metal or coated with it.**

So RAW at least, there does not appear to be any difference mechanically. So it's very unlikely you'll be able to save money through this process.

As for whether you can get your preexisting weapon coated or not, that all boils down to your DM. I can't imagine there are a lot of DMs that would permit full Adamantine Weapons but not permit preexisting weapons to be coated, but since it's an Optional Rule, you technically can't guarantee they'll permit them at all in the first place.